# vector bundle $\pi : E \rightarrow M$ and any $x \in M$: $\forall v \in E_x \exists s \in \Gamma(E) $s.t $s(x) = v$

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle

I am trying to prove this

For any vector bundle $\pi : E \rightarrow M$ and any $x \in M$:

$\forall v \in E_x \exists s \in \Gamma(E)$   s.t $s(x) = v$

$\Gamma(E)$ is the space of (smooth) sections of the vector bundle

Unfortunately I have nothing really useful to put here, I haven't gotten anywhere, plus I don't have much experience with diff geometry proofs. I would be nice if someone could show me how it is done as an example.

Comment: what do you mean by " the collection of tangent bundles over $M$"? As far as i am aware there is exactly one tangent bundle over $M$ (which would be a specific vector bundle). Usually $\Gamma(E)$ would denote the space of (smooth) sections of the vector bundle $\pi$.

Comment: @jd27yeah that is what I meant, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in M$ and $v \in E_x$ be arbitrary.
First, let $E \cong M\times \mathbb{R}^n$ be trivial. Then $v \cong (x, v')$. Take the "constant" section $s: M \to E, \, p \mapsto (p,v')$.

Now let $E$ be arbitrary. Then, by the above, there is some neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ of $x$ and a local section $s': U \to E$ with $s'(x) = v$. Take a smooth bump function $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ with $\text{supp}f \subseteq U$ and $f(x) = 1$. Define
$$s: M \to E, \, s(p) = \begin{cases} f(p)s'(p), & p \in U \\
0_p, & p \in M \smallsetminus \text{supp} f \end{cases}$$
where $0_p \in E_p$ is the zero-vector. Then $s$ is well-defined, smooth on the open sets $U$ and $M \smallsetminus \text{supp} f$ and $M = U \cup (M \smallsetminus \text{supp} f)$, i.e. $s \in \Gamma(E)$. Furthermore, $s(x) = f(x)s'(x) = v$.